# Promise is resolved before async operation completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I want to make a call to a Google Maps API and use the result to call another API (that is my eventual goal, right now I just want to print the results to the console.)  My problem is that the promise resolves before the API call and I end up with a result of undefined.

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const geospacial = require('./geospacial.js');
const trailapi = require('./trailapi.js');

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index');
});

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let activity = req.body.activity;
  let radius = req.body.radius;

  let getUserCoords = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    let userCoords = geospacial.getCoords(req.body.zip);
    resolve(userCoords);
  });

  getUserCoords.then((result) => {
    console.log("data: " + result);
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

The Google Maps API (geospacial.js)

```
const https = require('https');
require('./env.js');  // comment out for production

// Source: https://gist.github.com/clauswitt/1604972
const getDistance = (start, end) => {
  const earthRadius = 6371.008;
  let lat1 = parseFloat(start.latitude);
  let lat2 = parseFloat(end.latitude);
  let lon1 = parseFloat(start.longitude);
  let lon2 = parseFloat(end.longitude);

  let dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
  let dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  lat1 = lat1 * Math.PI / 180;
  lat2 = lat2 * Math.PI / 180;

  let a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
          Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
  let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  let d = earthRadius * c;
  let kilometers = Math.round(d * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2);
  let miles = Math.round(kilometers * .621371);
  console.log(miles);
  return miles;
};

// getDistance({latitude: 39.72122192, longitude: -80.51956177},{latitude: 40.02198029, longitude: -79.90330505}); // for testing

const getCoords = (addressData) => {
  let body = '';
  let req = https.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addressData + '&key=' + process.env.googleAPIKey, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      let result = JSON.parse(body);
      let coords = result.results[0].geometry.location;
      console.log(coords);
      return coords;
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
};
// getCoords('15351');  // for testing

module.exports = { 
  getCoords: getCoords,
  getDistance: getDistance
};
```

Comment: The `new Promise` should be done in `getCoords`, not in `getUserCoords`. The `return` in the asynchronous callback doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getCoords has an async call so you are resolving the promise before getCoords returns a value.  You need to resolve the promise in the callback of your async function.

`let getUserCoords = geospacial.getCoords(req.body.zip);`

```
const getCoords = (addressData) => {
  // getCoords returns a promise
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let body = '';
    let req = https.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addressData + '&key=' + process.env.googleAPIKey, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      let result = JSON.parse(body);
      let coords = result.results[0].geometry.location;
      console.log(coords);
      resolve(coords);  // promise resolves inside the callback of your async function
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
      reject(e);
      console.error(e);
    }); 
  });
 })
};


// getUserCoords now holds the returned promise and will fire .then() when the promise is resolved
getUserCoords.then(function(coords) { 
  console.log(coords); 
});
```

Comment: You `return` before installing the error handler. Better put it inside the promise executor callback, and `reject` when it happens.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Thank You!  I'm still trying to wrap my head around promises.

Answer (score 1):

what `getCoords` don't return a promise, so it doesn't work.
maybe you can change it like this:

```
const getCoords = (addressData) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let body = '';
      let req = https.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addressData + '&key=' + process.env.googleAPIKey, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(data) {
          body += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
          let result = JSON.parse(body);
          let coords = result.results[0].geometry.location;
          console.log(coords);
          resolve(coords);
        });
      });

      req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e);
        reject(e)
      });

  })

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getCoords` function has a flaw: it never returns anything. Ever.

`https.get` is async, and `req.on` is also async. So you do two async operations in `getCoords`, but never return anything.

You *may* think that the return statement in the `'end'` event handler returns for `getCoords`, but **it doesn't.** The return located in the event handler returns for the *event handler* function (that function you start after "`res.on('end',`").

No worries, you're on the right track; use a `Promise`!

```
const getCoords = (addressData) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do your stuff
    // when you want to return a value, resolve:
    resolve(apiResponse);
  });
};
```

Now `getCoords` will return a Promise!

Your code to print out it's response should look a little like this now:

```
geospacial.getCoords(req.body.zip).then((result) => {
  console.log("data: " + result);
});
```

Which

1. Calls `geospacial.getCoords`
2. Calls the resulting `Promise`'s `then`
3. (Eventually) resolves and prints out your result!